# reload kohana controller/action using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, kohana, kohana-3

In Kohana 3.1 how do you use ajax (with jquery) to reload a contollers action and then update the relevent content in the view?

e.g. I would like a controller `/classes/controller/user.php` with the action `public function action_bio() { ... }` to display a grid of 3 user avatars (user1 - user3), and fetch the user biography from db and displays it inside `#content` div of the user provided by the id parameter in the url (routed to default as user1). Each avatar is a link to the relevent user biography i.e. `href="/user/bio/user3"`.

I would like the switching of the biography to be asynchronous so when an avatar is clicked I would like to use jquery to prevent default event and then re-run action_bio - passing it the new user id parameter. I then want to replace #content with the new biograpahy action_bio outputs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting us to write all your code ?

You just have to send an AJAX request to Kohana (/user/bio/user3). 
In Kohana you fetch the data from the database. You format it the way you want (JSON, HTML or XML) then you send it as a response to your AJAX request. Finally you place / reformat the response data to your HTML.

Comment: or I didn't understand your question, if there's one.